# Launch VS Code with `--disable-gpu` flag by default

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-code

I'm having lag spikes in VS Code because of the hardware acceleration.

How can I get VS Code to always launch with the flag `--disable-gpu` (when launching from the command line and also from the context menu)?

Comment: Windows should allow you to provide additional command line arguments via Properties when you right-click on the executable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[VSCode 1.40 (Oct. 2019)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_40#_disable-gpu-acceleration) now has the solution I was looking for!

> #### Disable GPU acceleration
>
> We have heard issue reports from users that seem related to how the GPU is used to render VS Code's UI.
>   These users have a much better experience when running VS Code with the additional `--disable-gpu` command-line argument.
>   Running with this argument will disable the GPU hardware acceleration and fall back to a software renderer.
>
> **To make life easier, you can add this flag as a setting so that it does not have to be passed on the command line each time.**
>
> To add this flag:
>
> - Open the Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>).
> - Run the **Preferences: Configure Runtime Arguments** command. This command will open an `argv.json` file to configure runtime arguments.
>     You might see some default arguments there already.
> - Add `"disable-hardware-acceleration": true`.
> - Restart VS Code.
>
> Note: Do not use this setting unless you are seeing issues!

Answer (score 2):

For me, this worked:

Go to properties => compatibility => Run this program in compatibility mode for Windows 7

This issue has been going on for 3 years and still no fix.
 (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/15211)